# Using data of a compiled code in future

Tags: export, import, data, save

I have run a huge amount of code to find a 9 by 9 matrix called A. I want to use elements of this matrix in future when I open the Mathematica again. Is it possible? How can I do that? An step by step guide is very appreciated.

Comment: What Mathematica version? In M11.3 you can use [`Iconize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Iconize).

Comment: I am using Mathematica 10.3 :( @CarlWoll

Comment: Look at this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/173325/45431) for one possibility.

Comment: I'd like to mention that you can also `Export` your data (e.g. as .m or .wdx. file) and `Import` it later...

Comment: Or even export it as a CSV or something. This problem is not unique to Mathematica.

Comment: Another possibility might be to to edit your init.m file to include `A={{...}};` You can search M.S.E. or MMA documentation on how to use init.m.